# Permuting subgroups with the same finite index in free abelian group

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, permutations, geometric-group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with finite index $m$. Let $\phi$ be an automorphism on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Then $\phi$ corresponds to a matrix in $ \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

**Question**: What is the bound for the *smallest $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$, such that $\phi ^n(H) = H$*? Is it possible to get a **linear** or even **sublinear** bound?

**Thoughts so far**: Let $a(m)$ be the number of subgroups in $G$ with index $m$, then $a(m)$ is bounded by a polynomial but not a linear function in $m$. It follows that $n$ is bounded by a polynomial in $m$. I was wondering if this bound can be improved,  it seems unlikely for the automorphism to go through all the subgroups of this index.

Any references for this question would be really appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: We have $a(m)=m+1$ for $m$ prime, and ${\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb Z})$ maps onto ${\rm SL}(2,m)$, which acts transitively on the subgroups of index $m$, with  elements of order $(m+1)/2$. So you cannot expect a sublinear bound.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt, could you explain why if we have an element with order $(m+1)/2$ in $\operatorname{SL}(2,m)$, it acts **transitively** on the subgroups of index $m$?

Comment: When $m$ is prime there are $m+1$ subgroups of index $m$, so an element of order $(m+1)/2$ cannot act transitively on them. It has two orbits of length $(m+1)/2$. That is just a well-known property of the group ${\rm PSL}(2,m)$. I am afraid that I am still unsure whether there is a linear bound on $n$, which is an interesting question.