# Permuting subgroups with the same finite index in finitely generated free abelian group

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, permutations, geometric-group-theory

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4521459/976076).

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with finite index $m$. Let $\phi$ be an automorphism on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Then $\phi$ corresponds to a matrix $M$ in $ \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$. Suppose that all eigenvalues of $M$ are $1$.

**Question**: What is the bound for the *smallest $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$, such that $\phi ^n(H) = H$*? Is it possible to get a **sublinear** bound?

**Thoughts**: From the comment in the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4521459/976076), we know that we cannot find a sublinear bound for general $M$.
I am trying to find out under what conditions we would get a sublinear bound. When $M$ is the identity we have a constant bound, I was wondering if a sublinear bound would hold for other matrices.

Thank you for reading.